# Django Rest Framework filtering a field with null and multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using Django Rest Framework and want to filter the queryset in a view based on a certain field name.

The filter values would be null and additionally any other particular value for the field `blog_category` which is a `ForeignKey` value. So filter query should be on two query params

```
class Blog(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [DjangoCustomModelPermissions]
    queryset = Blog.objects.all().select_related("blog_category")
    serializer_class = Blog_Serializer
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
    filterset_fields = {'blog_category': ['isnull', 'exact', 'in']}
```

I have added the lookup fields `isnull` to filter null values

I have tried the following url requests but they do not work

```
/blog/?blog_catgeory__in=1,null
/blog/?blog_catgeory__in=1,isnull
/blog/?blog_catgeory__in=1,isnull=true
/blog/?blog_catgeory__in=1&blog_category__isnull=true
```

How do I get this work?

##### Edit After answer Javohir Elmurodov's answer

I made the following modifications but it still does not work

```
class NumberInFilter(django_filters.BaseInFilter, django_filters.NumberFilter):
    pass


class BlogFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    blog_category = NumberInFilter(field_name='blog_category', lookup_expr='in')
    blog_category__isnull = BooleanFilter(
        field_name='blog_category', lookup_expr='isnull')


class Blog_ListView(ListData, CreateData, CustomGenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [DjangoCustomModelPermissions]
    queryset = Blog.objects.all().select_related("blog_category")
    serializer_class = Blog_Serializer
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
    filterset_class = BlogFilter
```

I tried the following links

```
/blog/?blog_catgeory=1&blog_category__isnull
/blog/?blog_catgeory=1&blog_category__isnull=true
```

Still does not work

I want to search for all entries in queryset that are `null OR a particular value in blog_category`

Comment: did you try `/blog/?blog_catgeory__in=1&blog_category__isnull`?

Comment: @sudden_appearance Yes I had tried this. It returns only the results with ```blog_catgeory__in=1```

Comment: Do you have any `blog_category` null Blogs. Is Foreign key `null=True`

Comment: @JavohirElmurodov Yes

Comment: Could you try `blog_category__isnull = BooleanFilter( field_name='blog_category', lookup_expr='isnull')` to `blog_category_isnull = BooleanFilter( field_name='blog_category', lookup_expr='isnull')`, because it conflict with autofilter.

Comment: @JavohirElmurodov Had Tried that also, that too did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above problem can be solved by overriding the filter method

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from django_filters import CharFilter

class BlogFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    blog_category = CharFilter(field_name='blog_category_mast',
                               lookup_expr='exact',method='include_null')

    def include_null(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(**{f'{name}__isnull': True}) | Q(**{name: value})
        )


class Blog(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [DjangoCustomModelPermissions]
    queryset = Blog.objects.all().select_related("blog_category")
    serializer_class = Blog_Serializer
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
    filterset_class = BlogFilter
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s not always appropriate to directly match a filter to its model field’s type, as some lookups expect different types of values. This is a commonly found issue with `in`, `range`, and `isnull` lookups.

While the underlying column type for `category` is an `integer`, `isnull` lookups expect a `boolean` value.

You can check in [Filter and lookup expression mismatch (in, range, isnull)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/tips.html#filter-and-lookup-expression-mismatch-in-range-isnull)

Comment: I tried what you proposed, it still does not work. Please see the updated question for the modifications that I made